# Gravity and Air resistance

Tags: forces

How is it that the air resistance doesn't counteract the force of gravity by falling objects and cause the object to accelerate less than 9.8 unless it reaches terminal velocity. Even when the air resistance is almost as strong as the force of gravity, the object accelerates at 9.8m/s - why?

Comment: Who says that it does? Can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 2):

The air resistance causes a drag force $F_D$ which is a *function* of the object's velocity and points in the *opposite* direction of it.

At low velocity usually:

$$F_D=k_1v,\tag{1}$$

where $k_1$ is a *drag coefficient* and $v$ is the velocity.

At higher velocity (when flow around the object is turbulent):

$$F_D=k_2v^2$$

An object in *free fall* is always subject to the Earth's acceleration $g$, causing its *weight* $mg$. The equation of motion (Newton) then becomes:

$$ma=mg-F_D$$

As the drag force $F_D$ is *proportional* to the velocity, eventually the weight and drag force cancel out:

$$mg=F_D\implies ma=0\implies a=0$$

In the low velocity case the *analytical solution* is quite simple:

$$ma=mg-k_1v$$

With $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$:

$$m\frac{dv}{dt}=mg-k_1v$$
$$m\frac{dv}{mg-k_1v}=dt$$
$$-\frac{m}{k_1}\int_{v_0}^{v(t)}\frac{d(mg-k_1v)}{mg-k_1v}=\int_0^tdt$$
$$\ln\frac{mg-k_1v(t)}{mg-k_1v_0}=-\frac{k_1}{m}t$$
$$mg-k_1v(t)=(mg-k_1v_0)e^{-k_1t/m}$$
$$v(t)=\frac{1}{k_1}\big[mg-(mg-k_1v_0)e^{-k_1t/m}\Big]$$
For $t\to+\infty$:
$$v_{terminal}=\frac{mg}{k_1}$$
Since as $v_{terminal}$ is invariant of time that means:

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=0$$

So there is no **net acceleration** acting on the object anymore: the Earth's *acceleration* $g$ and the drag force's *decceleration* cancel each other out perfectly.

Comment: Just to add a small comment to @Gert's answer: from the formula of velocity you can calculate the acceleration and you see that it's not constant $g$, but it's exponentially decreasing towards $0$